# jmonkey doesn't run in my computer

Tags: opengl, jmonkeyengine

Today I decided to start developing a 3D game , I googled and found [JMonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.org/). I installed   it and it successfully installed but when run, I can't create a project rather it is continuously showing this two message in  message box.

1. org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid enum (1280)
2. java.lang.illegalstateexception:framebuffer doesn't have any renderbuffers attached

i am using [DELL vostro 1014](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/vostro-1014/pd) and no any extra graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

That usually happens if you are trying to run a fullscreen mode that your computer does not support.

To find which modes are supported, do this:

```
GraphicsDevice device =
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
```